# How to find unmatched rows with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two large xml files, one of which has the following format:

```
<Persons>
<Person>
<ID>1</ID>
<LAST_NAME>London</LAST_NAME>
</Person>
<Person>
<ID>2</ID>
<LAST_NAME>Twain</LAST_NAME>
</Person>
<Person>
<ID>3</ID>
<LAST_NAME>Dikkens</LAST_NAME>
</Person>
</Persons>
```

The second file has the following format:

```
<SalesPersons>
<SalesPerson>
<ID>2</ID>
<LAST_NAME>London</LAST_NAME>
</SalesPerson>
<SalesPerson>
<ID>3</ID>
<LAST_NAME>Dikkens</LAST_NAME>
</SalesPerson>
</SalesPersons>
```

I need to find those records from file 1, which does not exist in file 2. Although I have it done using for-each loop, such an approach is taking a substantial amount of time. Is it possible to somehow make it run faster using a different approach?

Comment: The "key" to improve performance on lookups in XSLT is usually not switching from `for-each` to `apply-templates` but instead is to use `xsl:key` e.g. `<xsl:key name="sales-person" match="SalesPerson" use="concat(ID, '|', LAST_NAME)"/>` and then to use the `key` function (it is a bit complicated in XSLT 1 to change scope between two documents but for that `for-each` and a variable helps). Consider to show us your existing code if you need help in improving that.

Comment: Unfortunately, my version of xslt does not recognize xsl:key element.

Comment: You tag a question as xslt and xslt-1.0 but don't have support for features like `xsl:key`? It doesn't look like you are using XSLT 1 as specified by the W3C in 1999 then.

Comment: This I have to re-confirm, I tried to add it into the source code, it did not show any error, but when I switched to design mode (I am using Oracle SOA 11.1.1.7), it gives  Line Number:(56) : Error: "xsl:key" XSL Element Currently not Supported

Comment: I did a quick search on Google, the error may be misleading, it is advised not to switch to GUI mode, I shall try the steps you suggested, let's see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using a key can help to improve performance on lookups:

```
  <xsl:key name="sales-person" match="SalesPerson" use="concat(ID, '|', LAST_NAME)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="Persons/Person">
          <xsl:variable name="person" select="."/>
          <!-- need to change context document for key function use -->
          <xsl:for-each select="$doc2">
              <xsl:if test="not(key('sales-person', concat($person/ID, '|', $person/LAST_NAME)))">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="$person"/>
              </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

That assumes you have bound `doc2` as a variable or parameter with e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('sales-persons.xml')"/>`.